# Export inside functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import, export

Is it possible to export from **inside** functions in JavaScript ?
I tried the following code but it doesn't work. I got a error when I try to import my function from other files.

```js
let dynExport = {};

function dynamicExport(o) {
     // Generate code ...
    const dynamicFunction = () => {
        // Some stuff
    };

    dynExport["DYNAMIC_NAME"] = dynamicFunction;
    export dynamicFunction as "DYNAMIC_NAME"; // Syntax Error
}

module.exports = dynExport;
```

> Attempted import error: 'DYNAMIC_NAME' is not exported from 'whatever'.

I am compiling the code with `npm start` from create-react-app

Comment: How would you want to import such a dynamically exported thing? It won't be visible at the beginning of runtime. Are you expecting to have logic such that, if something dynamic is imported, the appropriate `dynamicExport` has necessarily been called beforehand?

Comment: Yes the idea is to call dynamicExport for each of my modules when I create my redux store.

Comment: Importing the `dynExport` and then referencing its `DYNAMIC_NAME` property would be enough, right?